Double integral - change of varibles to polar coordinates
I was given the following integral :
\begin{align}
& \iint_{D}\,\sqrt{\,{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,}\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\[2mm]
\mbox{such that}\quad
& D = \left\{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid (x-1)^2 + y^2 < 1\right\}
\end{align}

I know I can solve this using the substitution
$$
x = r\cos\left(\theta\right),\quad
y = r\sin\left(\theta\right)
$$ but I tried to do it using
$$
x = 1 + r\cos\left(\theta\right)\quad\mbox{and}\quad y = r\sin\theta
$$ but for some reason that substitution doesn't seem to work: I don't understand why.
After substituting I get :
$$
\iint_{E}r\,\sqrt{\,{r^{2} + 2r\cos\left(\theta\right) + 1}\,}\,
\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r
$$

Now when I try $t = r^{2} + 2r\cos\left(\theta\right) + 1$ ( $t$ is a function of $\theta$ ), when substituting the limits of $\theta$ $\left(0 \le \theta \le 2\pi\right)$ into $t$ I get that $t$ goes from $r^{2} + 2r + 1$ to $r^{2} + 2r + 1$ meaning the value of the inner integral is $0$.
But that's not the correct answer, what did I do wrong here ?.




Your $\theta$ here is not actually the $\theta$ in polar coordinates. More likely, try to sketch the region $D$. Do you see any things on the left plane?

didn't get you here, if I substituted $x= 1+ r\cos\theta$ don't I measure the angle from the point $(1,0)$ with the positive x-axis? in that case i still need $\theta$ to be in the range $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, no?

Forget the multivariable part for a moment, the substitution you suggested doesn't actually solve the integral. You cannot use a substitution where $dt=0$ at multiple points on your domain of integration. This is an implicit requirement that is subtle and usually not taught explicitly, but you can see that doing such a substitution would create multiple copies of your integral with the absolute values ignored, hence canceling out when they aren't supposed to.

Your $t$ is a function of $\theta$ but not conversely. To fix this, split your integral in 2 (equal) parts: from $0$ to $\pi$ and from $\pi$ to $2\pi$.

The integral in polar coordinates is
$$\int r^2 \ dr \  d\phi$$ for $$r \in (0,\ 2)\ , \ - \frac{r}{2}\ \le \ \cos \phi \ \le \ \frac{r}{2}  $$
by $$\left(r \frac{r}{2}-1\right)^2 + r^2\left(1-\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^2\right)\  = \ 1$$
and so
$$\int _0^2 \ r^2 \ \left(\int _{-\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}^{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)} \ d\phi\right)  \ dr = \frac{32}{9}$$
Numerical check
 Rationalize[
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, -Sqrt[2 x - x^2], Sqrt[2 x - x^2]}],  
    1/100]  
  32/9

 Rationalize[NIntegrate[r^2,{r,0,2},{\[Phi],-ArcCos[r/2],ArcCos[r/2]}],1/100]
  32/9


Using standard polar coordinates, $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, the region $D$ translates to the interior of the curve $r(\theta)=2\cos\theta$, and computing the integral is as easy as it will get for this problem.
$$\begin{align*}
I = \iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dA &= \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\cos\theta} r\sqrt{r^2} \, dr\,d\theta \\
&= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \int_0^{2\cos\theta} r^2 \, dr\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{16}3 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \cos^3\theta \, d\theta = \boxed{\frac{32}9}
\end{align*}$$
OP's substitution of $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta+1,r\sin\theta)$ makes subsequent evaluation far more cumbersome albeit technically manageable. Two methods are outlined below.

Integrating w.r.t. $r$ first:
$$\begin{align*}
f(\theta) &:= \int_0^1 r \sqrt{1+r^2+2r\cos\theta} \, dr \\
&= \int_0^1 r \sqrt{(r+\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta} \, dr \\
&= \int_{\cos\theta}^{1+\cos\theta} (r-\cos\theta) \sqrt{r^2+\sin^2\theta} \, dr \\
&= \sin^2\theta \int_{\cot\theta}^{\csc\theta+\cot\theta} \left(r\sin\theta-\cos\theta\right) \sqrt{r^2+1} \, dr \\
&= \sin^2\theta \left[\frac{\sin\theta}{3}\left(1+r^2\right)^{3/2} - \frac {\cos\theta}2 r\sqrt{1+r^2} + \frac{\cos\theta}2 \operatorname{arsinh} r\right]_{\cot\theta}^{\cot\tfrac\theta2}
\end{align*}$$
By symmetry, the integral w.r.t. $\theta$ over $[0,2\pi]$ is twice that over $[0,\pi]$ and so $\left(1+\cot^2\theta\right)^{1/2}=\color{red}+\csc\theta$. The trig-only terms are easy to integrate with the help of the double angle identity, while the hyperbolic expression can be broken down with integration by parts.
$$\begin{align*}
I &= 2 \int_0^\pi f(\theta) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac23 \int_0^\pi \left(\sin^3\theta\csc^3\frac\theta2 - 1\right)\,d\theta - \int_0^\pi \cos\theta\left(3\cos\frac\theta2-\cos\theta+\cos\frac{3\theta}2\right) \, d\theta \\
&\qquad + \int_0^\pi \sin^2\theta\cos\theta \left(\operatorname{arsinh}(\cot\theta)-\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\cot\frac\theta2\right)\right) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac23\left(\frac{32}3-\pi\right) - \left(\frac{16}5-\frac\pi2\right) + \frac16\int_0^\pi \sin^3\theta \left(2\csc\theta-\csc\frac\theta2\right) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{176}{45}-\frac\pi6 + \frac16\left(\pi-\frac{32}{15}\right) = \boxed{\frac{32}9}
\end{align*}$$

Integrating w.r.t. $\theta$ first:
$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+r^2+2r\cos\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= 2 \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{1+r^2+2r\cos(2u)} \, du & \theta=\pi-2u \\
&= 4(1+r) \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{1-\frac{4r}{(1+r)^2}\sin^2u} \, du \\
\implies I &= 4 \int_0^1 r(1+r) E\left(\frac{2\sqrt r}{1+r}\right) \, dr \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 r \left(\left(r^2-1\right) K(r) + 2 E(r)\right) \, dr \\
&= \frac49 \lim_{r\to1} \left(\underbrace{\left(3r^4-2r^2-1\right)}_{\to0}K(r) + \left(7r^2+1\right) \underbrace{E(r)}_{\to1}\right) = \boxed{\frac{32}9}
\end{align*}$$
Rewriting of the integrand follows from the identity $(138)$ listed here. Closed forms for integrals of $z^{2n+1}K(z)$ and $z^{2n+1}E(z)$ can be found here $(K)$ and here $(E)$.
